# How can you do something while a MediaRecorder is recording?

Tags: java, android

I started my MediaRecorder when the user presses a button with:

```
recorder.start();
```

and I stop it with `recorder.stop();` when the user presses another button. How can I do something like:

```
while(recorder is recording){
    //do stuff here
}
```

I also have `recorder.setMaxDuration(5000);`

Is there an easy way to accomplish this task?

Comment: can you be more specific what you want to do between start and stop ?

Answer (score 1):

I've made up a simple example of what you are trying to do using swing. (I have never done any android programming, but hopefully the ideas will help you).

Clicking start will start a new thread & print "do something" every second.
Clicking stop will stop that thread printing.

[image]

**GUI**

```
public class MyGui {

static JButton startButton;
static JButton stopButton;
static RecorderThread thread;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                thread = new RecorderThread();
                thread.start();
                startButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        stopButton = new JButton("stop");
        stopButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                thread.kill();
                startButton.setEnabled(true);
                stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Media Recorder");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(startButton);
        panel.add(stopButton);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(100, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Thread**

```
public class RecorderThread extends Thread {

    volatile boolean isRunning = true;

    public void kill(){
        isRunning = false;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            System.out.println("Do stuff");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

All the best!

Comment: MediaRecorder is a platform library on Android, the platform targeted by the question tags .  That oversight makes the GUI code inapplicable, though an Android version would not be all that distinct in form, as much as terminology.  What is universal though is that **Your flag needs to be volatile.**

Comment: Ah thank you, I've never done any android programming wasn't sure how similar it might be to swing, hopefully the idea might help though.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Thread once the media recorder has started with the code that you want to execute. At the end, when the user press the end button you should change the condition control in order to let the thread to finish.